# Make UIRotationGestureRecognizer more sensible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, ios5

I have added the following gesture recognizer to my user control:

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]
          initWithTarget:self
          action:@selector(ViewRotated:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:rotate];

-(void)ViewRotated:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"rotated");
}
```

so far everything works great and the gesture responds fast whenever I rotate my fingers on the iOS device.

---

**Now the problem comes when adding the pinch gesture recognizer to the same view. When I add:**

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ViewPinched:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:pch];
//...
// ...

-(void)ViewPinched:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender{
     NSLog(@"Pinched");
}
```

**that pch event fires 70% of the time. I have to really rotate my fingers in a perfect way so that the rotate gesture triggers instead of the pinch one. How can I make the rotate gesture more sensible so that it triggers more easily?**

Comment: Well your 2 gestures are conflicting and that's what causing the issue.

In this case it would might better to create your own gesture recongizers rather than using the system build in recognizers....

Comment: or maybe if I could delay the pinch gesture recognizer it will be great. I don't mind if it takes .4 seconds for the pinch gesture to take effect. the rotate gesture responds very fast if the other gesture is not there. I do not know how to delay it or maybe that is not even possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the gesture recognizers' delegate and return `YES` from `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method. This allows multiple gesture recognizers to work simultaneously.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Great thing to know.

Comment: I also didn't know that!  I told my users to rotate with their wrist rather than their fingertips LOL!